# Logging in JUnit Testcases

Tags: java, logging, junit

I am just curious:

Is it a good practice to enable logging in JUnit test cases? We are running around 300 JUnits test classes each having an average 10-12 test cases.

Also any guidance on best practices are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you should not log in a JUnit test. Normally a unit test is green -> no need for logs. If it is red -> you're usually faster if you use a debugger.